# saving to a network location using vb2012

Tags: ftp

I am trying to have my app save data in a text file stored on a network location. I scoured the tutorials out there but I haven't seen anything close to what I need done.

I have my app writing the data to a text file using comma separated values and saving the file in yyyyMMdd.txt format appending the file so multiple users will not overwrite. I need the file stored on a network somewhere though since it will be many users and we don't have a shared drive.

so basically it looks like this:
Application run locally -> writes to txt file locally

And I need this:
Application run locally -> writes to txt file in a network

If I just upload the file, it will overwrite the existing file (at least I think so). I need it to just append the stored file.

any advice is appreciated!

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: I need a point in the direction of how I can accomplish this. I need the file to be store in a shared location so every person who uses the app can append it rather than overwrite it. ill update the question with a summary.

Comment: So just create the file on a network share or on a UNC path... I'm still not clear what the problem is here

Comment: I don't have a network share. I have no clue what a UNC path is but I will research that now :) Quick check - I can't use that either. I have a server I can run or I can use FTP but I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: i may have to just save the data individually using date_time.txt and find a way to parse every txt document that is saved.